# Google authorization window - change application name

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

I'm using google calendar in my web, so I need users to authorizate it to access google calendar.

The problem is, when I generate the url which shows you to login into google to let my application to access the calendar, it says "amazonaws.com", not my application name.

I'm pretty sure I've configured everything in google developers console. I've chosen a product name, a main page url, a logo url... But it keeps showing amazonaws (I guess it takes that name because the webhook redirects to a https://-----.amazonaws.com domain)

How can I solve my problem? Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm generating the url with google nodejs's sdk, I don't know if that could be relevant.

[image: Example]

[image: Example2]

Answer (score 1):

You can change this in Credential Page of the developer console.

[image]

Once you changed it will reflect. Try testing it on [OAuth 2.0 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

[image]

Hope this helps.